# Angular formatters and parsers within a directive not functioning as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formatting

I'm trying to build a small datetime directive which allows a user to select a date with three dropdowns (date, month, year), which should then get parsed into a string resembling `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` for the server to interpret - this is my variable within ngModel. Likewise, if a default value is present, it should be formatted to an object with component values.

#### What `format` should produce

`'2012-09-27'` should become `{ year: 2012, month: 'September', date: 27 }`

#### What `parse` should produce

`{ year: 2008, month: 'October', date: 3 }` should become `2008-10-03`.

Currently, it is not working as expected. This is not a formatting dates issue, rather it seems to be an Angular pipeline issue (something like I'm not correctly understanding how `$parsers` and `$formatters` works).

Here is my directive's template:

```
<select ng-model="datetimevalue.date" ng-options="day.value as day.display for day in days">
</select>
<select ng-model="datetimevalue.month" ng-options="month.value as month.display for month in months">
</select>
<select ng-model="datetimevalue.year" ng-options="year for year in years()">
</select>
```

Here is my directive being used:

```
<datetime ng-model="file.originated_at"></datetime>
```

Here is my directive code:

```
angular.module('directives.datetime', []).directive('datetime', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            datetimevalue: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            $scope.days = [];
            $scope.days.push({ value: 0, display: '-'});

            for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                $scope.days.push({ value: i, display: i });
            }

            $scope.months = [
                { value: 0, display: '-'},
                { value: 1, display: 'January'},
                { value: 2, display: 'February'},
                { value: 3, display: 'March'},
                { value: 4, display: 'April'},
                { value: 5, display: 'May'},
                { value: 6, display: 'June'},
                { value: 7, display: 'July'},
                { value: 8, display: 'August'},
                { value: 9, display: 'September'},
                { value: 10, display: 'October'},
                { value: 11, display: 'November'},
                { value: 12, display: 'December'}
            ];

            $scope.years = function() {
                var years = [];

                var currentYear = moment().year();

                if (typeof $scope.startYear !== 'undefined') {
                    var startYear = $scope.startYear;
                } else {
                    var startYear = 1950;
                }

                while (currentYear >= startYear) {
                    years.push(currentYear);
                    currentYear--;
                }

                return years;
            };

            //convert data from view format to model format
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                return moment({
                    year: data.year,
                    month: data.month - 1,
                    date: data.date,
                    hour: data.hour,
                    minute: data.minute,
                    second: data.second
                }).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            });

            //convert data from model format to view format
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                var dt = moment(data);

                console.log(data);

                return {
                    year: dt.year(),
                    month: dt.month() + 1,
                    date: dt.date(),
                    hour: dt.hour(),
                    minute: dt.minute(),
                    second: dt.second()
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: '/js/templates/datetime.html'
    }
});
```

Right now, if I select a date using my date picker, the object on the exposed parent scope looks like the view data, not the model data.

I.e. I'm expecting `2012-09-27` but instead I have `{ year: 2012, month: 'September', date: 27 }`.

For what it's worth, I'm using `moment.js` as a date library.

Comment: I think you've swapped the function of the `$formatters` and `$parsers`. `$formatters` outputs your DOM view value and `$parsers` outputs the value stored as your model value. You want your DOM view value to be `2012-09-27` but your formatter is returning the an object

Comment: You sure? Most documentation I've read suggests that `$formatters` takes a model value and returns a view value (which is where I need an object). Likewise, `$parsers` takes a view value and converts to a model value. http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. `$formatters` produces view value and `$parsers` produces model value. You want your view value to be `2012-09-27` right? i.e. your `$formatter` should be returning this but it's returning an object

Comment: View value needs to be an object so I can have access to all the individual date components separately, model value needs to be a date string.